# conjugate subgroup and normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

1. Let $G=S_{3},$ and consider the subgroup $H=\langle(1,2)\rangle=\{(1),(1,2)\}$
   (a) List the elements of the conjugate subgroup $g H g^{-1}$ where $g=(1,2,3)$
2. Is $H$ a normal subgroup of $S_{3} ?$ Explain.

For first part the answer I get are conjugate subgroup contains only two elements as  ${id, (3,2,1)}$ check whether this is correct or not ?

Now to tackle part B we need conjugate subgroup is same  $g H g^{-1}$ $=$ $H$. But this is not case since from part 1 we can see that?

Comment: Your answer to 1. cannot be correct, since $\{id, (3 \ 2 \ 1)\}$ is not a subgroup. Check your computations ( the conjugate of transposition is necessarily a transposition). If you find a $g$ such that $gHg^{-1}\neq H$, then YES, you can conlude that $H$ is not a normal subgroup.

Comment: Can you help me regarding 1 @GreginGre it turn out same from my side?

Answer (score 2):

Note that by definition, we have $gHg^{-1}=\{g(1)g^{-1}, g(1,2)g^{-1}\}$. Clearly, $g(1)g^{-1}=(1)$, as $(1)$ commutes with anything.

In the below, I'm assuming you apply permutations from right to left.

As for $g(1,2)g^{-1}$, we get
$$
(1,2,3)(1,2)(1,3,2)
$$
So what permutation is this? First, let's see where $1$ goes. First, $g^{-1}$ sends $1$ to $3$, then $(1,2)$ doesn't touch the $3$, and then $g$ sends it back to $1$.

Where does $2$ go, then? First, $g^{-1}$ sends it to $1$, then $(1,2)$ sends that $1$ to $2$, and finally $g$ sends the $2$ to $3$.

So $g(1,2)g^{-1}$ sends $1$ to $1$ and $2$ to $3$. Which by the definition of permutation means the last element $3$ must be sent to $2$. Thus $g(1,2)g^{-1}=(2,3)$, and we get
$$
gHg^{-1}=\{(1), (2,3)\}
$$